# MeteorTips Second Application Tutorial - Validations

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working on the Methods 2 chapter of [MeteorTips' Second tutorial](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/methods-part-2/), which is basically just building a todo application with several lists.

I moved my code for adding tasks to a list into a method, and decided to try adding some validations to the tasks so that it cannot be blank and it cannot be less than 3 characters. I have the validation working, but my code is returning a Match failed error when running check(currentList, String). I can see that it is not fetching the list's ID, and stroing undefined in the variable.

My question is, how do I fix it?

### Code in Question

#### HTML Template

```
<template name="addTodo">
  <form class="add-todo">
    Create a task
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a task here..." name="todoName" />
  </form>
</template>
```

#### JavaScript

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
...
  Template.addTodo.events({
    'submit form': function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
...
  Template.addTodo.onRendered(function () {
    var validator = $('.add-todo').validate({
      submitHandler: function (event) {
        var todoName = $('[name="todoName"]').val();
        var currentList = this._id;
        console.log(todoName + " | " + currentList); // Assuming user inputs New Task, this returns New Task | undefined
        Meteor.call('createListItem', todoName, currentList, function (error, results) {
          if (error) {
            validator.showErrors({
              todoName: error.reason
            });
          } else {
            $('[name="todoName"]').val('');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
...
}

Meteor.methods({
...
  'createListItem': function (todoName, currentList) {
    check(todoName, String);
    check(currentList, String);
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    var data = {
      name: todoName,
      completed: false,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      createdBy: currentUser,
      listId: currentList
    }
    if(!currentUser){
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-logged-in", "You're not logged in.");
    }
    return Todos.insert(data);
  },
});
```

---

If you have a Cloud 9 account, you can view the complete code. The server may not always be running the application as I have a free account:

Editor (read-only): https://ide.c9.io/blueknightone/meteor-todos

Comment: Is _id a string? That is what is assigned to currentList.

Comment: Yes, _id is supposed to be a string, and it worked before it moved t out of the 'submit form' function and into the submitHandler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain the reference to the original `this`, because your context is changing in your `submitHandler` function. As a result, you could use `var self = this;` and then access the template's data context via `self.data`:

```
Template.addTodo.onRendered(function() {
    var self = this;
    var validator = $('.add-todo').validate({
        submitHandler: function(event) {
            var todoName = $('[name="todoName"]').val();
            var currentList = self.data._id;
            console.log(todoName + " | " + currentList);
            Meteor.call('createListItem', todoName, currentList, function(error, results) {
                if (error) {
                    validator.showErrors({
                        todoName: error.reason
                    });
                } else {
                    $('[name="todoName"]').val('');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to use [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you could implement the following approach:

```
Template.addTodo.onRendered(function() {
    var validator = $('.add-todo').validate({
        submitHandler: (event) => {
            var todoName = $('[name="todoName"]').val();
            var currentList = this.data._id;
            console.log(todoName + " | " + currentList);
            Meteor.call('createListItem', todoName, currentList, function(error, results) {
                if (error) {
                    validator.showErrors({
                        todoName: error.reason
                    });
                } else {
                    $('[name="todoName"]').val('');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what I thought might be happening, and your suggestion worked.